# Convert doc to image with unsupported fonts

Tags: fonts, converters, aspose.words

I've already used aspose classes to convert word document to png files.
But for exact conversion all applied in text file fonts must be installed on system (or we must have folder with these fonts on server).
If there is not appropriate font resulting images are shown incorrectly.

So is there any possibility (maybe another API) to avoid problem of unsupported fonts?

Could you please so kind to give any advice?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two optioons to handle missing-fonts situation.

**Declare a Default Font**

You can declare default font using `FontSettings` class. When the fonts used by document are not found on system during rendering, Aspose.Words falls back to default font. Check our documentation for [How to Specify the Default Font to use when Rendering](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to+Specify+the+Default+Font+to+use+when+Rendering) in .Net and [How to Specify the Default Font to use when Rendering](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to+Specify+the+Default+Font+to+use+when+Rendering) in Java.

**Dynamically choose fonts**

Aspose.Words provides a callback when the fonts used by document are not found on the system. The callback handler that you define can dynamically substitute fonts during rendering. It is declared via `SaveOptions` class. Check [How to Receive Notification of Missing Fonts and Font Substitution during Rendering](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to+Receive+Notification+of+Missing+Fonts+and+Font+Substitution+during+Rendering) in .Net and [How to Receive Notification of Missing Fonts and Font Substitution during Rendering](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to+Receive+Notification+of+Missing+Fonts+and+Font+Substitution+during+Rendering).

You can combine both options together.

Disclosure: I am a developer at Aspose.

Comment: I know about this options.
The fact is that document may include different fonts and languages, so I don't see how setting of default font can help. I created class implementing IWarningCallback and saw results when default font was 'Times New Roman' and when default font was 'null'. But it doesn't help when we have 'multi-font' document.

Comment: I thought about .addFontSubstitutes method but I would like to do it dynamically.
There are two issue problem:
1) What is firstly performed: substitution or getting warning message? It means "when we can to set another font?"
2) How to choose properly font to substitute? Using Charset property? Or something similar?

Anyway thank you for your attention and reply.

Comment: Kindly share the document and the code you have written. I shall try to propose a solution or workaround. You can also submit the document privately via our [support forums](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/).